# Cast exception in UrlImageViewHelper library, while trying to cast BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, urlimageviewhelper

I am using the UrlImageViewHelper lib developed by Koushik Dutta (Koush). Here is what I am doing

1. Load images from a url into imageview which are inside a gridview.
2. Image loading works perfectly and is quite fast.

I am trying to save the image loaded inside the imageview, as a wallpaper but it crashes and throws up a casting exception.

**The code**

```
UrlViewImageHelper.setURLDrawable(imageView,"some url here");
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

**The above line throws this exception**

```
02-26 06:54:07.987: E/AndroidRuntime(19659): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper$ZombieDrawable
```

How do I get the image inside the imageView as a bitmap? What am I doing wrong?

I understand that I can use some other library such as Android Universal Image Loader (have not tried it yet),SmartImageView (good but slow), but koush's library is quite fast and simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLViewImageHelper downloads the image in separate thread asynchronously, hence at the point you call imageView.getDrawable(), the image not loaded yet.

What u can try is to register a callback object to be notified when image finished loading:

```
UrlViewImageHelper.setURLDrawable(imageView,url, defaultResource, new UrlImageViewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Bitmap loadedBitmap, String url, boolean loadedFromCache) {
        // your method here
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    }
}) ;
```